# Regulating multiple +5V sources to one output to increase current, but avoid interference/noise

Tags: circuit-design, usb, voltage-regulator, dc, avr

I'm designing a circuit with 4 USB 2.0 upstream ports that each connect to their own AVR (ATMEGA32U4), 1 master and 3 slave connected via I2C, master then communicates with a USB controller via SPI, then that controller connects to a USB hub with 4 downstream ports.

My concern is power, I'd like to be able to combine the +5V from each upstream USB port so that the downstream ports can be powered adequately, but also not introduce noise that would interfere with anything else on the board, specifically the USB hub.

One option is to keep all these AVRs and downstream ports powered separately by their corresponding upstream ports, but space is limited and routing over a bunch of different voltages sounds iffy to me, with my cursory understanding of PCB design.

My questions are:

- Can I regulate these +5V lines to one output to multiply/increase the current and what would I use to achieve this?
- Are there other options, besides using an external power source, that I'm not seeing here?

Comment: I have difficulties to understand the problem. A block schematic of this setup might help to understand how the use or combination of USB, SPI, I2C and power distribution is intended.